# Returning a collection of DataContracts

Tags: wcf, collections, datacontract

I have a situation where one of our developers is returning back a collection of DataContracts back from a WCF service.  I don't think Microsoft intended DataContracts to be used in this fashion.  If a list of items needs to be returned back from a service, then a single DataContract should be returned of which one of the DataMembers contains a collection of said items.

Can anyone verify the best practice in this scenario?  Let me know if you need any other info.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with you. I always use `Message Pattern`/`Request-Response Pattern` in WCF.

For example, any method would take a `Request` (or it's descendents) object and return a `Response` (or it's descendants) object.

### Example:

for method `GetUsers()`, signature would be something like:

```
GetUsersResponse GetUsers(GetUsersRequest request);
```